# Is the core of UWP IE or Edge

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge

I want to print out the user agent information of WebView with code.
Make sure WebView core is IE or Edge.and find out the browser version number

Comment: Are you using the [webView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)? If yes, I suggest you refer to the [CoreWebView2Settings.UserAgent Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.useragent?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.790-prerelease). it can help you to get the user agent information of webView2.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  I Print the user agent information ``Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; WebView/3.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18363``

Comment: If possible, please try to provide detailed information about the issue. Please inform us about your development environment, post the sample code. Which webView you are using for making this test? do you mean, you got the user agent string and you want to find the information related to the browser engine from it?